# Simple way to change html table cell in c# if statement

Tags: c#, html

I have a html table that I am display my data in and I want to change the html table cells colors based on my if statement. I have runat="server" and I have system.web.ui.htmlcontrols but I can't find a clear way of how to change a html tables cell colors. I have been looking/trying for a couple hours. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

```
if(Order != true)
{
    //code for changing html table cell goes here
}
```

Attempted this method but html table did not show nor did the TableRow or TableCell

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.Text = "Testing";
cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
row.Cells.Add(cell);
table.Rows.Add(row);

table.Rows[0].Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
```

Here is my method on page load excluded adding data

```
public static List<LineData> getData()
{
    if(Order != true)
    {
        //code for changing html table cell goes here
    }
}
```

Front end table start

```
<table style="border: medium solid #FFFFFF; 
              background-color: #000000; 
              border-color:White; 
              position: fixed;"
       border="2" 
       width="100%" 
       title="myTable" 
       runat="server" >
```

Comment: please also show the front-end code and a more relevant part of your server-side code.

Comment: @Bobby5193 sorry for lack of knowledge but what more would be needed form front end and server side for relevence?

Comment: well the part where you define the table, and where the handler that contains that "if" is triggered

Comment: @Bobby5193 got you be back

Comment: and where are you adding the table? you should add it to an existing element in your html that is runat='server'

Comment: @Bobby5193 added new info hopefully it is helpful.

Comment: try this : myTable.Controls.Add(table); at the end of your code

Comment: @Bobby5193 probably self explanatory but front or server?

Comment: server side, after you set the backColor

Comment: @Bobby5193 I can't access the myTable title I gave it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46277/discussion-between-bobby5193-and-kpt-khaos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the Id of the table in order to see it on the server side.

```
<table style="border: medium solid #FFFFFF; 
              background-color: #000000; 
              border-color:White; 
              position: fixed;"
       border="2" 
       width="100%" 
       id="myTable" 
       runat="server" >
```

Also, If you already have a table defined, then you can just add rows to it, there is no need to define another one on the server-side.